# TDengine insertion use taos_stmt apis

Tags: database, tdengine

After creating super table and tables, call `taos_load_table_info` to load the table information. Then initialize stmt by calling `taos_stmt_init` and `taos_stmt_set_tbname` to set up table name.
Create the `TAOS_BIND` object with the following attributes: 
`buffer_type = TSDB_DATA_TYPE_NCHAR` 
`buffer_length = sizeof(str)` 
`buffer = &str` 
`length = sizeof(str)` 
Then call `taos_stmt_bind_param` and `taos_stmt_add_batch`, and finally execute with `taos_stmt_execute`. 
The problem is that the insertion failed because I check the shell and use `select *` to look for the data but it only shows an empty column.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you first try to insert a simple nchar type data to check whether it is the taos_stmt API's problem. If that insertion success, then you can also check if the insert nchar string has the same length as `str` variable. Sometimes, `buffer_length` is greater than or equal to `length`. If the actual size of your nchar data is less than the `length` value in `TAOS_BIND`, then tdengine will still analyze the binding value with other extra empty values and will fail to insert.